# My r3f model cannot be scaled nor its position changed

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to scale my model and change its position, but its not happening- I must be missing something. It's not webpack as the rest is updating fine and the model is loading. I used gltfjsx to create this file.

```
export default function Model({ ...props }) {
  const group = useRef()
  const { nodes } = useGLTF('./mymodel')
  const material = useMemo(() => {
        if (props.layer === DEFAULT_LAYER) return new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: new THREE.Color('rgba(62,53,105,1)'), roughness: 0.2, metalness: 0.9 })
        else return new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: new THREE.Color('rgba(52,95,75,1)') })
      }, [props.layer]);
  
  return (
    <group ref={group} dispose={null} position={[0,-500,0]} scale={[0.01, 0.01, 0.01]} {...props}>
      <mesh geometry={nodes.Node.geometry} material={material} 
        layers={props.layer} receiveShadow castShadow />
    </group>
  )
}
```

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Canvas camera={{ position: [0, 20, 12], fov: 35, near: 0.1, far: 2000 }} gl={{ antialias: true }} onCreated={state => state.gl.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 0)}>
        <Suspense fallback={null}>    
          <Stage intensity={1}>
            <Model layer = {DEFAULT_LAYER} />
          </Stage>
        </Suspense>
      </Canvas>
      <Loader />
    </>
  )
}
```

I have placed scale and position in the Model, mesh and group objects but none make a difference. How come? I can't change my camera position either.

My imports for Model.jsx:

```
import {useRef, useMemo} from 'react'
import { useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei'
import * as THREE from 'three'
```

My imports for App.jsx:

```
import React, { Suspense, useRef, useMemo } from 'react'
import { Canvas, useThree, useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { Loader, useFBO, Stage, Effects, Environment, OrbitControls } from '@react-three/drei'
import Model from './FortunaDraco'
import { FXAAShader } from 'three-stdlib'
import { AdditiveBlendingShader } from './shaders/AdditiveBlendingShader'
import { VolumetricLightShader } from './shaders/VolumetricLightShader'
import './App.css'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having this issue it was because of Stage